# How to insert value into another table after I inserted values into a different table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I insert or change the 'submitted' field in 'contestants' table into '1' after I inserted data into 'tbl_rate' table ??

Table 'tbl_rate'

```
---------------------------------
rate_id  judge_id  cont_id  score
---------------------------------
14      | 36     |     5 |  10
---------------------------------
```

Table 'contestants'

```
id  event_id  name  gender  address  date_created  submitted
------------------------------------------------------------
5     | 25  |john doe |male |Texas |  2017-03-06|   0
------------------------------------------------------------

WHERE 'id' in 'contestants' table is foreign key in 'cont_id' on 'tbl_rate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make two individual query, one for `tbl_rate` (insert) and another for `contestants` (update) and run it in sequence i.e. `tbl_rate` first and on success of it run second query.

You can also use transaction to maintain the data integrity.

Comment: It Works Thank you!! But there are different judges to score for a contestant, so how should I do it if there are more than 1 judges to score 
 for a specific contestant?

Comment: Use an ON INSERT AFTER trigger to update the other table.

Comment: ©ynnhoj24, do you meant that one of multiple judges  will rate or multiple judges will rate a single contest. If multiple judges will rate a single contest then you need to insert as many records in tbl_rate as the no. of judges with same cont_id

Comment: Also, please accept the answer if you think it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_rate (judge_id, cont_id, score) VALUES ('".$judge_id."', '".$cont_id."', '".$score."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $sql = "UPDATE contestants SET submitted=1 WHERE id=".$cont_id;
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
  }
 } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
```

and define the variables before your query